# Cutting MPEG-TS file via ffmpegwrapper?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, ffmpeg

I have MPEG-TS files on the device. I would like to cut a fairly-exact time off the start of the files on-device.

Using [FFmpegWrapper](https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper) as a base, I'm hoping to achieve this.

I'm a little lost on the C API of ffmpeg, however. Where do I start?

I tried just dropping all packets prior to a start PTS I was looking for, but this broke the video stream.

```
    packet->pts = av_rescale_q(packet->pts, inputStream.stream->time_base, outputStream.stream->time_base);
    packet->dts = av_rescale_q(packet->dts, inputStream.stream->time_base, outputStream.stream->time_base);

    if(startPts == 0){
        startPts = packet->pts;
    }

    if(packet->pts < cutTimeStartPts + startPts){
        av_free_packet(packet);
        continue;
    }
```

How do I cut off part of the start of the input file without destroying the video stream? When played back to back, I want 2 cut segments to run seamlessly together.

```
ffmpeg -i time.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -ss $CUT_POINT -map 0 -y after.ts
ffmpeg -i time.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -to $CUT_POINT -map 0 -y before.ts
```

Seems to be what I need. I think the re-encode is needed so the video can start at any arbitrary point and not an existing keyframe. If there's a more efficient solution, that's great. If not, this is good enough.

EDIT: Here's my attempt. I'm cobbling together various pieces I don't fully understand copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856803/how-to-cut-video-with-ffmpeg-c-api). I'm leaving off the "cutting" piece for now to try and get audio + video encoded written without layering complexity. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on `avcodec_encode_video2(...)`

```
- (void)convertInputPath:(NSString *)inputPath outputPath:(NSString *)outputPath
                 options:(NSDictionary *)options progressBlock:(FFmpegWrapperProgressBlock)progressBlock
         completionBlock:(FFmpegWrapperCompletionBlock)completionBlock {
    dispatch_async(conversionQueue, ^{
        FFInputFile *inputFile = nil;
        FFOutputFile *outputFile = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;

        inputFile = [[FFInputFile alloc] initWithPath:inputPath options:options];
        outputFile = [[FFOutputFile alloc] initWithPath:outputPath options:options];

        [self setupDirectStreamCopyFromInputFile:inputFile outputFile:outputFile];
        if (![outputFile openFileForWritingWithError:&error]) {
            [self finishWithSuccess:NO error:error completionBlock:completionBlock];
            return;
        }
        if (![outputFile writeHeaderWithError:&error]) {
            [self finishWithSuccess:NO error:error completionBlock:completionBlock];
            return;
        }

        AVRational default_timebase;
        default_timebase.num = 1;
        default_timebase.den = AV_TIME_BASE;
        FFStream *outputVideoStream = outputFile.streams[0];
        FFStream *inputVideoStream = inputFile.streams[0];

        AVFrame *frame;
        AVPacket inPacket, outPacket;

        frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
        av_init_packet(&inPacket);

        while (av_read_frame(inputFile.formatContext, &inPacket) >= 0) {
            if (inPacket.stream_index == 0) {
                int frameFinished;
                avcodec_decode_video2(inputVideoStream.stream->codec, frame, &frameFinished, &inPacket);
//                if (frameFinished && frame->pkt_pts >= starttime_int64 && frame->pkt_pts <= endtime_int64) {
                if (frameFinished){
                    av_init_packet(&outPacket);
                    int output;
                    avcodec_encode_video2(outputVideoStream.stream->codec, &outPacket, frame, &output);
                    if (output) {
                        if (av_write_frame(outputFile.formatContext, &outPacket) != 0) {
                            fprintf(stderr, "convert(): error while writing video frame\n");
                            [self finishWithSuccess:NO error:nil completionBlock:completionBlock];
                        }
                    }
                    av_free_packet(&outPacket);
                }
                if (frame->pkt_pts > endtime_int64) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        av_free_packet(&inPacket);

        if (![outputFile writeTrailerWithError:&error]) {
            [self finishWithSuccess:NO error:error completionBlock:completionBlock];
            return;
        }

        [self finishWithSuccess:YES error:nil completionBlock:completionBlock];
    });
}
```

Comment: So now I am adding an answer. If no more efficient answers are there, i hope i get the bounty,

Comment: You should only cut on Random Access Points (I frames) so you can search for the nearest PTS where you also find a Random Access Indicator (I think it was called RAP flag, you should look for it in the header) If you want to cut on every other frame then you can only do this by transcoding the video

Comment: @StefanKendall, is my answer alright. Do you think anything more should be added? Also, if you find a more efficient way, keep me updated.

Comment: @StefanKendall, also, I deleted my comment in which I had mentioned the link, as I have added the  link in my answer.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall, you should move `-ss` to before `-i` else ffmpeg will go about decoding all frames and then discard, as opposed to seeking to inpoint.

Answer (score 22):

The FFmpeg (libavformat/codec, in this case) API maps the ffmpeg.exe commandline arguments pretty closely. To open a file, use [avformat_open_input_file](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga31d601155e9035d5b0e7efedc894ee49)(). The last two arguments can be NULL. This fills in the AVFormatContext for you. Now you start reading frames using [av_read_frame()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61) in a loop. The pkt.stream_index will tell you which stream each packet belongs to, and avformatcontext->streams[pkt.stream_index] is the accompanying stream information, which tells you what codec it uses, whether it's video/audio, etc. Use [avformat_close()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#gae804b99aec044690162b8b9b110236a4) to shut down.

For muxing, you use the inverse, see [muxing](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html) for details. Basically it's [allocate](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__core.html#gac7a91abf2f59648d995894711f070f62),  [avio_open2](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_8h.html#ade8a63980569494c99593ebf0d1e891b), [add streams](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__core.html#gadcb0fd3e507d9b58fe78f61f8ad39827) for each existing stream in the input file (basically context->streams[]), [avformat_write_header()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga18b7b10bb5b94c4842de18166bc677cb), [av_interleaved_write_frame()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga37352ed2c63493c38219d935e71db6c1) in a loop, [av_write_trailer()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga7f14007e7dc8f481f054b21614dfec13) to shut down (and [free](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__core.html#gac2990b13b68e831a408fce8e1d0d6445) the allocated context in the end).

Encoding/decoding of the video stream(s) is done using libavcodec. For each AVPacket you get from the muxer, use [avcodec_decode_video2()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html). Use [avcodec_encode_video2()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__encoding.html) for encoding of the output AVFrame. Note that both will introduce delay so the first few calls to each function will not return any data and you need to flush cached data by calling each function with NULL input data to get the tail packets/frames out of it. av_interleave_write_frame will interleave packets correctly so the video/audio stream will not desync (as in: video packets of the same timestamp occur MBs after audio packets in the ts file).

If you need more detailed examples for avcodec_decode_video2, avcodec_encode_video2, av_read_frame or av_interleaved_write_frame, just Google "$function example" and you'll see full-fledged examples showing how to use them correctly. For x264 encoding, [set some default parameters](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) in the AVCodecContext when calling avcodec_open2 for encoding quality settings. In the C API, you do that using [AVDictionary](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__dict.html), e.g.:

```
AVDictionary opts = *NULL;
av_dict_set(&opts, "preset", "veryslow", 0);
// use either crf or b, not both! See the link above on H264 encoding options
av_dict_set_int(&opts, "b", 1000, 0);
av_dict_set_int(&opts, "crf", 10, 0);
```

[edit] Oh I forgot one part, the timestamping. Each AVPacket and AVFrame has a pts variable in its struct, and you can use that to decide whether to include the packet/frame in the output stream. So for audio, you'd use [AVPacket.pts](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVPacket.html#a73bde0a37f3b1efc839f11295bfbf42a) from the demuxing step as a delimiter, and for video, you'd use [AVFrame.pts](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html#a0452833e3ab6ddd7acbf82817a7818a4) from the decoding step as a delimited. Their respective documentation tells you in what unit they are.

[edit2] I see you're still having some issues without actual code, so here's a real (working) transcoder which re-codes video and re-muxes audio. It probably has tons of bugs, leaks and lacks proper error reporting, it also doesn't deal with timestamps (I'm leaving that to you as an exercise), but it does the basic things that you asked for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

static AVFormatContext *inctx, *outctx;
#define MAX_STREAMS 16
static AVCodecContext *inavctx[MAX_STREAMS];
static AVCodecContext *outavctx[MAX_STREAMS];

static int openInputFile(const char *file) {
    int res;

    inctx = NULL;
    res = avformat_open_input(& inctx, file, NULL, NULL);
    if (res != 0)
        return res;
    res = avformat_find_stream_info(inctx, NULL);
    if (res < 0)
        return res;

    return 0;
}

static void closeInputFile(void) {
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < inctx->nb_streams; n++)
        if (inavctx[n]) {
            avcodec_close(inavctx[n]);
            avcodec_free_context(&inavctx[n]);
        }

    avformat_close_input(&inctx);
}

static int openOutputFile(const char *file) {
    int res, n;

    outctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    outctx->oformat = av_guess_format(NULL, file, NULL);
    if ((res = avio_open2(&outctx->pb, file, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
        return res;

    for (n = 0; n < inctx->nb_streams; n++) {
        AVStream *inst = inctx->streams[n];
        AVCodecContext *inc = inst->codec;

        if (inc->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            // video decoder
            inavctx[n] = avcodec_alloc_context3(inc->codec);
            avcodec_copy_context(inavctx[n], inc);
            if ((res = avcodec_open2(inavctx[n], avcodec_find_decoder(inc->codec_id), NULL)) < 0)
                return res;

            // video encoder
            AVCodec *encoder = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264");
            AVStream *outst = avformat_new_stream(outctx, encoder);
            outst->codec->width = inavctx[n]->width;
            outst->codec->height = inavctx[n]->height;
            outst->codec->pix_fmt = inavctx[n]->pix_fmt;
            AVDictionary *dict = NULL;
            av_dict_set(&dict, "preset", "veryslow", 0);
            av_dict_set_int(&dict, "crf", 10, 0);
            outavctx[n] = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            avcodec_copy_context(outavctx[n], outst->codec);
            if ((res = avcodec_open2(outavctx[n], encoder, &dict)) < 0)
                return res;
        } else if (inc->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            avformat_new_stream(outctx, inc->codec);
            inavctx[n] = outavctx[n] = NULL;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Don’t know what to do with stream %d\n", n);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if ((res = avformat_write_header(outctx, NULL)) < 0)
        return res;

    return 0;
}

static void closeOutputFile(void) {
    int n;

    av_write_trailer(outctx);
    for (n = 0; n < outctx->nb_streams; n++)
        if (outctx->streams[n]->codec)
            avcodec_close(outctx->streams[n]->codec);
    avformat_free_context(outctx);
}

static int encodeFrame(int stream_index, AVFrame *frame, int *gotOutput) {
    AVPacket outPacket;
    int res;

    av_init_packet(&outPacket);
    if ((res = avcodec_encode_video2(outavctx[stream_index], &outPacket, frame, gotOutput)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to encode frame\n");
        return res;
    }
    if (*gotOutput) {
        outPacket.stream_index = stream_index;
        if ((res = av_interleaved_write_frame(outctx, &outPacket)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write packet\n");
            return res;
        }
    }
    av_free_packet(&outPacket);

    return 0;
}

static int decodePacket(int stream_index, AVPacket *pkt, AVFrame *frame, int *frameFinished) {
    int res;

    if ((res = avcodec_decode_video2(inavctx[stream_index], frame,
                                     frameFinished, pkt)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to decode frame\n");
        return res;
    }
    if (*frameFinished){
        int hasOutput;

        frame->pts = frame->pkt_pts;
        return encodeFrame(stream_index, frame, &hasOutput);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *input = argv[1];
    char *output = argv[2];
    int res, n;

    printf("Converting %s to %s\n", input, output);
    av_register_all();
    if ((res = openInputFile(input)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open input file %s\n", input);
        return res;
    }
    if ((res = openOutputFile(output)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open output file %s\n", input);
        return res;
    }

    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket inPacket;

    av_init_packet(&inPacket);
    while (av_read_frame(inctx, &inPacket) >= 0) {
        if (inavctx[inPacket.stream_index] != NULL) {
            int frameFinished;
            if ((res = decodePacket(inPacket.stream_index, &inPacket, frame, &frameFinished)) < 0) {
                return res;
            }
        } else {
            if ((res = av_interleaved_write_frame(outctx, &inPacket)) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write packet\n");
                return res;
            }
        }
    }

    for (n = 0; n < inctx->nb_streams; n++) {
        if (inavctx[n]) {
            // flush decoder
            int frameFinished;
            do {
                inPacket.data = NULL;
                inPacket.size = 0;
                if ((res = decodePacket(n, &inPacket, frame, &frameFinished)) < 0)
                    return res;
            } while (frameFinished);

            // flush encoder
            int gotOutput;
            do {
                if ((res = encodeFrame(n, NULL, &gotOutput)) < 0)
                    return res;
            } while (gotOutput);
        }
    }
    av_free_packet(&inPacket);

    closeInputFile();
    closeOutputFile();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with my first-pass attempt. I'm getting an exception that I don't even know how to start to debug.

Comment: Do you have a backtrace? Some possible answers are that after av_init_packet(&outPacket), you need to set outPacket.data = NULL and outPacket.size = 0, or that you may not have opened the outputVideoStream.stream->codec variable using avcodec_open2()? The backtrace would make it more obvious what went wrong.

Comment: It's EXC_BAD_ACCESS, so I get no output and the application ceases immediately. How should I be using avcodec_open2 Right now I'm using avcodec_copy_context from the input stream to the output stream.

Comment: see edit in original post for tested+functional code.

Comment: I'll try this tonight!

Comment: Converting /Users/stefankendall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KickflipOnPrem-cmrkfryrotrmmwfowcweavrsynmo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.xctest/left_camera6.ts to /Users/stefankendall/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D3917F17-D0B4-4C39-BE1F-28DBECABA79E/data/Documents/headcut.ts
[NULL @ 0x7f9a44826600] No codec provided to avcodec_open2()
Failed to open output file /Users/stefankendall/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D3917F17-D0B4-4C39-BE1F-28DBECABA79E/data/Documents/headcut.ts

[mpegts @ 0x7f9a44027400] Invalid packet stream index: 1
Failed to write packet

Comment: That second error repeats until avcodec_encode_video2 throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: You don't have ffmpeg compiled with libx264 support. Re-compile with libx264 support, or install pre-compile binaries with libx264 support.

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje would using avformat_seek_file() instead of av_seek_frame() be enough to avoid manually handling timestamps?

Comment: No, since @StefanKendall wanted frame-exact cutting, and all av* functions only seek to nearest keyframes.

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje, I don't suppose you can help **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38326396/2057709)** too? Basically I don't use iOS so how to advise someone to set a `c:v copy` equivalent in FFmpegWrapper? No worries but check it out if you can...

Comment: I tried to compile your example but I always have got_packet_ptr = 0 as output from avcodec_encode_video2. So my output file is empty. Can you clarify what could be wrong?

Comment: Difficult to say without more specific information, I'd suggest to open a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: Ok. I will try to do more investigation. Can you tell what version of FFMpeg you used to write this code?

Answer (score -3):

Check out the accepted answer of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/979633/how-to-split-and-join-without-transcoding-avc-mpeg-ts-video-files-in-windows-wit) question.

Basically in short, you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i time.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -ss $CUT_POINT -map 0 -y after.ts
ffmpeg -i time.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -to $CUT_POINT -map 0 -y before.ts
```

---

Just for reference, the accepted answer of that question is:

### How do I split and join files using `ffmpeg` while retaining all audio tracks?

As you have discovered, a bitstream copy will select only **one** (audio) track, as per the [stream specification documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection):

> By default, `ffmpeg` includes only one stream of each type (video, audio, subtitle) present in the input files and adds them to each output file. It picks the "best" of each based upon the following criteria: for video, it is the stream with the highest resolution, for audio, it is the stream with the most channels, for subtitles, it is the first subtitle stream. In the case where several streams of the same type rate equally, the stream with the lowest index is chosen.

To select *all* audio tracks:

```
ffmpeg -i InputFile.ts-c copy -ss 00:12:34.567 -t 00:34:56.789 -map 0:v -map 0:a FirstFile.ts
```

To select the *third* audio track:

```
ffmpeg -i InputFile.ts -c copy -ss 00:12:34.567 -t 00:34:56.789 -map 0:v -map 0:a:2 FirstFile.ts
```

You can read more about and see other examples of stream selection in the [advanced options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) section of the `ffmpeg` documentation.

I would also combine `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` from your original command into `-c copy` as above for compactness of expression.

## Split:

So, combining those with what you want to achieve in the two files in terms of splitting for later re-joining:

```
ffmpeg -i InputOne.ts -ss 00:02:00.0 -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:a OutputOne.ts
ffmpeg -i InputTwo.ts -c copy -t 00:03:05.0 -map 0:v -map 0:a OutputTwo.ts
```

will give you:

- **`OutputOne.ts`**, which is everything *after* the first two minutes of the first input file
- **`OutputTwo.ts`**, which is the *first* 3 minutes and 5 seconds of the second input file

## Join:

`ffmpeg` supports concatenation of files without re-encoding, [described extensively in its concatenation documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Create your listing of files to be joined (eg `join.txt`):

```
file '/path/to/files/OutputOne.ts'
file '/path/to/files/OutputTwo.ts'
```

Then your `ffmpeg` command can use the `concat demuxer`:

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -i join.txt -c copy FinalOutput.ts
```

Since you are working with `mpeg` transport streams (`.ts`), you *should* be able to use the concat **protocol** as well:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:OutputOne.ts|OutputTwo.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Per the example on the concat page linked above. I'll leave that up to you to experiment with.

Comment: Yeah, so how do I do this via the ffmpeg C apis? This is useless to me.