# How to cut videos/audios using FFmpeg C APIs

Tags: c++, c, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a function to cut videos/audios FFmpeg C APIs in C++. I started with the [remuxing.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c) example from FFmpeg GitHub repository, and tried to apply the same changes mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856803/how-to-cut-video-with-ffmpeg-c-api), but I'm getting blank screen in the beginning of the output equal to the duration that I want to cut. This is the function I came with (Differences between the function and the remuxing example noted with  `// <- HERE`):

```cpp
int cut_video(const char *in_filename, const char *out_filename, double from_seconds, double end_seconds) {
  const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = NULL;
  AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx = NULL, *ofmt_ctx = NULL;
  AVPacket *pkt = NULL;
  int ret, i;
  int stream_index = 0;
  int *stream_mapping = NULL;
  int stream_mapping_size = 0;

  pkt = av_packet_alloc();
  if (!pkt) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate AVPacket\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, in_filename, 0, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file '%s'", in_filename);
    goto end;
  }

  if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to retrieve input stream information");
    goto end;
  }

  av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, in_filename, 0);

  ret = av_seek_frame(ifmt_ctx, -1, from_seconds * AV_TIME_BASE, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY);  // <- HERE
  if (ret < 0) {                                                                    // <- HERE
    fprintf(stderr, "Error seek\n");                                                // <- HERE
    goto end;                                                                       // <- HERE
  }                                                                                 // <- HERE

  avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, out_filename);
  if (!ofmt_ctx) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create output context\n");
    ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
    goto end;
  }

  stream_mapping_size = ifmt_ctx->nb_streams;
  stream_mapping = (int *)av_calloc(stream_mapping_size, sizeof(*stream_mapping));
  if (!stream_mapping) {
    ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    goto end;
  }

  ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;

  for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
    AVStream *out_stream;
    AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
    AVCodecParameters *in_codecpar = in_stream->codecpar;

    if (in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO &&
        in_codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE) {
      stream_mapping[i] = -1;
      continue;
    }

    stream_mapping[i] = stream_index++;

    out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (!out_stream) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
      ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
      goto end;
    }

    ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, in_codecpar);
    if (ret < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters\n");
      goto end;
    }
    out_stream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
  }
  av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);

  if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
    ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (ret < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename);
      goto end;
    }
  }

  ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
  if (ret < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
    goto end;
  }

  while (1) {
    AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;

    ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, pkt);
    if (ret < 0) break;

    in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index];
    if (pkt->stream_index >= stream_mapping_size || stream_mapping[pkt->stream_index] < 0 ||
        av_q2d(in_stream->time_base) * pkt->pts > end_seconds) {  // <- HERE
      av_packet_unref(pkt);
      continue;
    }

    pkt->stream_index = stream_mapping[pkt->stream_index];
    out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index];
    log_packet(ifmt_ctx, pkt, "in");

    /* copy packet */
    av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
    pkt->pos = -1;
    log_packet(ofmt_ctx, pkt, "out");

    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, pkt);
    /* pkt is now blank (av_interleaved_write_frame() takes ownership of
     * its contents and resets pkt), so that no unreferencing is necessary.
     * This would be different if one used av_write_frame(). */
    if (ret < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
      break;
    }
  }

  av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
  av_packet_free(&pkt);

  avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);

  /* close output */
  if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
  avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

  av_freep(&stream_mapping);

  if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And here is how I call it:

```cpp
cut_video("/Users/aliosm/Desktop/1.mp4", "/Users/aliosm/Desktop/2.mp4", 10, 40);
```

I searched a lot on Google and I didn't find anything useful related to this specific use-case, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to do that by the help from #ffmpeg channel community on Libera.Chat IRC. The final code:

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
}

/**
 * @brief Print the information of the passed packet.
 *
 * @fn logPacket
 * @param avFormatContext AVFormatContext of the given packet.
 * @param avPacket AVPacket to log.
 * @param tag String to tag the log output.
 */
void logPacket(const AVFormatContext *avFormatContext, const AVPacket *avPacket, const QString tag) {
  AVRational *timeBase = &avFormatContext->streams[avPacket->stream_index]->time_base;

  qDebug() << QString("%1: pts:%2 pts_time:%3 dts:%4 dts_time:%5 duration:%6 duration_time:%7 stream_index:%8")
                  .arg(tag)
                  .arg(av_ts2str(avPacket->pts))
                  .arg(av_ts2timestr(avPacket->pts, timeBase))
                  .arg(av_ts2str(avPacket->dts))
                  .arg(av_ts2timestr(avPacket->dts, timeBase))
                  .arg(av_ts2str(avPacket->duration))
                  .arg(av_ts2timestr(avPacket->duration, timeBase))
                  .arg(avPacket->stream_index);
}

/**
 * @brief Cut a file in the given input file path based on the start and end seconds, and output the cutted file to the
 * given output file path.
 *
 * @fn cutFile
 * @param inputFilePath Input file path to be cutted.
 * @param startSeconds Cutting start time in seconds.
 * @param endSeconds Cutting end time in seconds.
 * @param outputFilePath Output file path to write the new cutted file.
 *
 * @details This function will take an input file path and cut it based on the given start and end seconds. The cutted
 * file will then be outputted to the given output file path.
 *
 * @return True if the cutting operation finished successfully, false otherwise.
 */
bool cutFile(const QString& inputFilePath, const long long& startSeconds, const long long& endSeconds,
                            const QString& outputFilePath) {
  int operationResult;

  AVPacket* avPacket = NULL;
  AVFormatContext* avInputFormatContext = NULL;
  AVFormatContext* avOutputFormatContext = NULL;

  avPacket = av_packet_alloc();
  if (!avPacket) {
    qCritical("Failed to allocate AVPacket.");
    return false;
  }

  try {
    operationResult = avformat_open_input(&avInputFormatContext, inputFilePath.toStdString().c_str(), 0, 0);
    if (operationResult < 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error(QString("Failed to open the input file '%1'.").arg(inputFilePath).toStdString().c_str());
    }

    operationResult = avformat_find_stream_info(avInputFormatContext, 0);
    if (operationResult < 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error(QString("Failed to retrieve the input stream information.").toStdString().c_str());
    }

    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&avOutputFormatContext, NULL, NULL, outputFilePath.toStdString().c_str());
    if (!avOutputFormatContext) {
      operationResult = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
      throw std::runtime_error(QString("Failed to create the output context.").toStdString().c_str());
    }

    int streamIndex = 0;
    int streamMapping[avInputFormatContext->nb_streams];
    int streamRescaledStartSeconds[avInputFormatContext->nb_streams];
    int streamRescaledEndSeconds[avInputFormatContext->nb_streams];

    // Copy streams from the input file to the output file.
    for (int i = 0; i < avInputFormatContext->nb_streams; i++) {
      AVStream* outStream;
      AVStream* inStream = avInputFormatContext->streams[i];

      streamRescaledStartSeconds[i] = av_rescale_q(startSeconds * AV_TIME_BASE, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, inStream->time_base);
      streamRescaledEndSeconds[i] = av_rescale_q(endSeconds * AV_TIME_BASE, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, inStream->time_base);

      if (inStream->codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO &&
          inStream->codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO &&
          inStream->codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE) {
        streamMapping[i] = -1;
        continue;
      }

      streamMapping[i] = streamIndex++;

      outStream = avformat_new_stream(avOutputFormatContext, NULL);
      if (!outStream) {
        operationResult = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        throw std::runtime_error(QString("Failed to allocate the output stream.").toStdString().c_str());
      }

      operationResult = avcodec_parameters_copy(outStream->codecpar, inStream->codecpar);
      if (operationResult < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error(
            QString("Failed to copy codec parameters from input stream to output stream.").toStdString().c_str());
      }
      outStream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
    }

    if (!(avOutputFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
      operationResult = avio_open(&avOutputFormatContext->pb, outputFilePath.toStdString().c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
      if (operationResult < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error(
            QString("Failed to open the output file '%1'.").arg(outputFilePath).toStdString().c_str());
      }
    }

    operationResult = avformat_write_header(avOutputFormatContext, NULL);
    if (operationResult < 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error(QString("Error occurred when opening output file.").toStdString().c_str());
    }

    operationResult = avformat_seek_file(avInputFormatContext, -1, INT64_MIN, startSeconds * AV_TIME_BASE,
                                         startSeconds * AV_TIME_BASE, 0);
    if (operationResult < 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error(
          QString("Failed to seek the input file to the targeted start position.").toStdString().c_str());
    }

    while (true) {
      operationResult = av_read_frame(avInputFormatContext, avPacket);
      if (operationResult < 0) break;

      // Skip packets from unknown streams and packets after the end cut position.
      if (avPacket->stream_index >= avInputFormatContext->nb_streams || streamMapping[avPacket->stream_index] < 0 ||
          avPacket->pts > streamRescaledEndSeconds[avPacket->stream_index]) {
        av_packet_unref(avPacket);
        continue;
      }

      avPacket->stream_index = streamMapping[avPacket->stream_index];
      logPacket(avInputFormatContext, avPacket, "in");

      // Shift the packet to its new position by subtracting the rescaled start seconds.
      avPacket->pts -= streamRescaledStartSeconds[avPacket->stream_index];
      avPacket->dts -= streamRescaledStartSeconds[avPacket->stream_index];

      av_packet_rescale_ts(avPacket, avInputFormatContext->streams[avPacket->stream_index]->time_base,
                           avOutputFormatContext->streams[avPacket->stream_index]->time_base);
      avPacket->pos = -1;
      logPacket(avOutputFormatContext, avPacket, "out");

      operationResult = av_interleaved_write_frame(avOutputFormatContext, avPacket);
      if (operationResult < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error(QString("Failed to mux the packet.").toStdString().c_str());
      }
    }

    av_write_trailer(avOutputFormatContext);
  } catch (std::runtime_error e) {
    qCritical("%s", e.what());
  }

  av_packet_free(&avPacket);

  avformat_close_input(&avInputFormatContext);

  if (avOutputFormatContext && !(avOutputFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    avio_closep(&avOutputFormatContext->pb);
  avformat_free_context(avOutputFormatContext);

  if (operationResult < 0 && operationResult != AVERROR_EOF) {
    qCritical("%s", QString("Error occurred: %1.").arg(av_err2str(operationResult)).toStdString().c_str());
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

The code is written in C++, and it is using some Qt related classes, you can remove them and use the code on plain C++ projects.

I tried my best to make it readable, I hope it is good and helpful.

---

- Update 1: I updated the code to fix a bug in it.
- Update 2: I updated the code to do some refactoring.